# Adaptive Bitrate Streaming (ABR)

Tags: system-design, adaptive-bitrate

How does an "Adaptive Bit Rate Streaming" works? For instance, how does Netflix or Youtube manages to continue playing the video from that very timestamp with a different resolution? How do they get to know about the bandwidth or network speed of any client? What if a particular video resolution was not available at the client's nearest OCA or CDN?